# setLocationData crash application

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

i m tring to start my application which crash on this code tired to solve it. E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.activity.NearbyHomeActivity.setLocationData(NearbyHomeActivity.java:543)

```
public static DatabaseReference profileRef;

public static void setLocationData(Context context) {
            if (context != null) {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    profileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
                }
                profileRef.child("latitude").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLat());
                profileRef.child("longitude").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLng());
                profileRef.child("location").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLat() + "," + VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLng());
                profileRef.child("address").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getArea());
                profileRef.child("city").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getCity());
                profileRef.child("country").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getCountry());
            }
        }
```

and this is my logcat what he said about this error when i launch it

```
01-02 02:24:53.123 2026-2026/? E/PagedView: updateCurrentPageScroll: childCount: 2currentPage0newX: 0
01-02 02:24:54.601 1785-12127/? E/AudioTrack: did not receive expected priority boost on time
01-02 02:25:00.365 12156-12156/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 42 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db-wal
01-02 02:25:08.546 2026-2026/? E/PagedView: updateCurrentPageScroll: childCount: 2currentPage0newX: 0
01-02 02:25:15.728 12239-12239/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-02 02:25:15.728 12239-12239/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-02 02:25:27.071 2026-2026/? E/PagedView: getScrollProgress: page: 0 : leftX: 0 delta: 0 scrollProgress : 0.0halfScreenSize360screenCenter360
01-02 02:25:27.071 2026-2026/? E/PagedView: getScrollProgress: page: 1 : leftX: 720 delta: -720 scrollProgress : -1.0halfScreenSize360screenCenter360
01-02 02:25:29.580 12293-12293/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.activity.NearbyHomeActivity.setLocationData(NearbyHomeActivity.java:543)
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.utility.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:219)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-02 02:25:29.711 1785-12292/? E/AudioTrack: did not receive expected priority boost on time
01-02 02:25:29.790 12293-12293/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.websmeet.vroumchat, PID: 12293
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.activity.NearbyHomeActivity.setLocationData(NearbyHomeActivity.java:543)
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.utility.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:219)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-02 02:25:30.273 12293-12356/? E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to parse Json response string to get message: No value for crashes
01-02 02:25:33.348 1785-12364/? E/AudioTrack: did not receive expected priority boost on time
01-02 02:25:33.934 12365-12365/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.activity.NearbyHomeActivity.setLocationData(NearbyHomeActivity.java:543)
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.utility.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:219)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-02 02:25:34.144 12365-12365/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.websmeet.vroumchat, PID: 12365
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.activity.NearbyHomeActivity.setLocationData(NearbyHomeActivity.java:543)
        at com.websmeet.vroumchat.utility.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:219)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-02 02:25:34.285 12365-12449/? E/FirebaseCrash: Unable to parse Json response string to get message: No value for crashes
01-02 02:26:02.930 12365-12389/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

0

i tried to insert try{} else{} and again not working

```
public static void setLocationData(Context context) {
        if(context!=null){
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
          try {
              if (firebaseUser != null) {
                  profileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
              } else {
                  profileRef.child("latitude").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLat());
                  profileRef.child("longitude").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLng());
                  profileRef.child("location").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLat() + "," + VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getLng());
                  profileRef.child("address").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getArea());
                  profileRef.child("city").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getCity());
                  profileRef.child("country").setValue(VroumchatApplication.getInstance().getCountry());
              }
          }
        }
    }
```

the problem is when launche the application it try to get Location before login but what i whant that get Location after login.

any help please.
thank you

finly i solved it by editing GPSTracker.java

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 second

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return ;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}




/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){

    if (location != null) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}


/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude() {

    if (location != null) {

        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity)mContext).finish();
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;

}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Always post the error stack from the logcat when you post a question regarding "my application crashes". But, a quick glance at your code I see `if (firebaseUser != null) {` without an `else` you just jump right in and use `profileRef.child` presumably when `firebaseUser == null` ?? But, only when you post the error stack will we really know which error is being thrown.

Comment: i updated thank you for your answer

Comment: but, which line is 54 in your code?

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please responde with @.

Comment: Is it solved now?

Comment: yes i pub the solution mybe this can help the others.

Answer (score 0):

profileRef not defined for else situation, also for the best error handling wrap the try{ }catch(Exception e){ } at least you can easly figure out where is the problem.